# Rendering form_for error messages outside of form div for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I render form_for error messages outside of the form_for div?

This is what I have now:

```
<div id="editUser_form", class="round">
<h1>Edit user</h1>

<%= form_for @user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
...
<% end %>
</div>
```

However, I want it to look more like this:

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>

<div id="editUser_form", class="round">
<h1>Edit user</h1>

<%= form_for @user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
</div>
```

The code above gives me an error because `:object => f.object` must be part of the form. Is there a way to pass the f.object to the shared/error_messages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object is @user, so you can do this:

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => @user %>
```

Anywhere that @user is defined, as long as the partial doesn't rely on anything else in the form object.

Comment: Thanks, Veraticus. This works. I'll accept your answer once stackoverflow lets me!

Answer (score 1):

`f.object` is just the object passed as the first argument to `form_for`, so:

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => @user %>
```